# How to put hint (placeholder) on border of TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, textfield

I would like to achieve something similar to this behaviour, but I could not find anything.

Idea is that TextField has a regular hint (placeholder).
Once the user starts typing, the hint goes to the top border.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you

declare TextEditingController

```
late TextEditingController username;
```

Declare controller for initState and dispose state

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    username = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    username.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Declare Widget:

```
 Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                controller: username,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'City',
                    hintText: 'Enter City Here'),
              ),
            ),
```

Your Screen result -> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the labelText property in the TextField and add decoration

```
TextField(
    decoration:InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Label',
    ),
)
```

Comment: how to change border color?